# Making extra money on the side

Tags: income, working-at-home

I was hoping to get some ideas about how to make extra money. I'm currently working as an undergraduate researcher for next to nothing, it allows me to pay rent but only barely. I need to make some extra money so I can do extra-curricular things. My background is computer engineering, with an emphasis on electronics, I have experience with Java, Python, and basic knowledge of HTML 5, C. If you guys have any ideas that would help me to make some extra money while using my current skill set that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I did was got a real job while in school.  With those skills you might be able to find remote work, or even one that works around your schedule.  It didn't pay great, but it paid great in comparison to what I had been making.  Heck, for you, waiting tables might pay better.

Comment: how is this about options? just reviewing the tags and wondering whether you have a speciality in options trading that is not evident from your question.

Comment: @MD-Tech: It's possible the questioner doesn't realize "options" refers to a kind of financial instrument, and is just looking for "options" in the lay sense (i.e., possible courses of action).

Comment: @MD-Tech I don't think it was meant as like stock options, more like what options would you suggest for funding my extracurricular life. I agree with Pete B.  A job worked well for me both times I was pursuing a degree and that is the advice I have given my son who is in college now.

Comment: @homer150mw perhaps I was nudging him to read tag descriptions before randomly adding them ;)

Comment: @homer150mw not wanting to continue this too much as it is getting chatty but my biggest tagging problem is on stack overflow because I work closely with the FIX protocol. Amazing how many people tag questions "fix" because they want a fix...

Comment: Options tag removed.

Comment: My college kinkos experience was invaluable.  I was able to excel because of my technological aptitude but I also got to learn to deal with the general public without having to serve food or coffee.  Personally, if you're studying, I wouldn't try to take contract programming work.  Clients can be very demanding and tracking down payment can be impossible.  A job with a paycheck is where you want to be, imo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for job/work advice and not a personal finance topic.

Answer (score 1):

With your knowledge/experience, you should easily be able to find work through one of the freelance developer sites out there.  It would let you work flexibly on your own schedule, and you can decide what types of work you're willing to do at rates you choose to work for.

You could always come up with your own ideas for a commercial website of some kind that could help generate some degree of passive income that won't interfere with your full-time work.  That's only limited by your imagination and creativity.

The third alternative is to find a "real" job (I chuckle at that one!) like most people do.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!